# hibernate - taking value using join table where the key used in the joint table is not primery key

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have three class A,B,C where

```
public class A{
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private String id;

 @Column(name = "bid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 String b_id
}

public class B{
 @id
 @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private String id;

 @Column(name = "cid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 String c_id;
 }

public class C{
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private String id;

 @Column(name = "property", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private String property
 }
```

I would like in one select get from A Hibernate pojo `c.property`

I noticed I can not achieve it by using `@JoinTable` because B primary key is not a combination of a & c keys .

I thought about doing one of the next :

1. Using `@loader` with namedQuery. It seems like a bad idea , I want on every select the the table would be created of namedQuery

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "A&B&C")
   @Loader(namedQuery = "all")
   @NamedNativeQuery(name = "all", query = "select * from A a join B b on a.bid = a.aid join C c on b.cid = c.id )
   ```
2. using @SecondaryTables is it possible ? for 3 ?

Is there another good solution ?

10x.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have IDs of other entities as fields of your entities. It looks like you should simply have a ManyToOne between A and B (several As refer to the same B), and a ManyToOne between B and C (several Bs refer to the same C).

So you should have, in A, instead of `b_id`:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "bid")
private B b;
```

and similarly, in B:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cid")
private C c;
```

Now, when you ,want to get the  property of an A, you simply need to call

```
String property = a.getB().getC().getProperty();
```

Comment: I cant change B and C